# How is the default ToString() method of Object class implemented?

Tags: c#, oop, casting

Imagine you have two of this simple classes:

```
class Class1
{
}

class Class2
{
}
```

We all know that all classes by default inherits from `object` class.

So imagine this code:

```
int num = new Random().Next(1, 3);
object obj = num == 1 ? new Class1() : new Class2();
Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
```

So based on random number the output will be `namespace.Class2` or `namespace.Class1`.
And note that I'm assigning these classes to `object` class.

My questions are:

1. How `ToString()` of `object`class can find out the original derived class type? (`namespace.Class2` or `namespace.Class1`)
2. Can we use the result of `ToString()` method to cast the type successfuly? If yes, How?

Comment: `this.GetType()`.

Comment: You tagged this OOP. Since this is the basics of OOP, I would suggest you read a good book or tutorial on the topic in general and not get bogged down with the details on how C# does it specifically.

Comment: There is no "original" derived class, `obj` is the derived class. As for implementation - [here](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Object.cs,39) it is.

Comment: "_Can we use the result of `ToString()` method to cast the type successfully?_" No, casting is a compile-time concept.

Comment: _"Can we use the result of ToString() method to cast the type successfuly?"_  in general you should not. At least I don't see any advantages over working with types with `case` expressions/pattern matching/type testing.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay you can check type name in code and cast to corresponding type =))))

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay; Of course he can. `if(obj.ToString()=="namespace.Class2"){Class2 c2 = (Class2)obj}`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I expect the OP means in a dynamic sense.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: if OP wants to create an instance of a class with a given string he needs reflection(`Activator.CreateInstance`), but i don't think that he wants that.

Comment: @GuruStron: "obj is the derived class" - no, `obj` is the name of a variable. It's not a class, derived or otherwise.

Comment: @JonSkeet as always correct wording. Yes, `obj` is a variable containing reference to instance of derived class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How ToString() of objectclass can find out the original derived class type? (namespace.Class2 or namespace.Class1)

When casting you do not change the object itself, only the *reference* to the object. So `ToString()` will still check the actual object type (and not the reference type) to find the correct method to call.

All objects have a [header](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/managed-object-internals-part-1-layout/) that contain type information a bunch of other stuff used by the runtime. Note that value types like int and struct lack such a header so will be more compact. However, these value types will be [boxed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/boxing-and-unboxing) if cast to object, and that will incur the object overhead, so it is best avoided where possible.

> Can we use the result of ToString() method to cast the type successfuly? If yes, How?

There is really no point. If you want to do a safe cast just do

```
if(obj is Class1 myClass1Reference){
    ...
}
```

You can also use [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) to essentially turn of type-checking, resulting in runtime errors instead of compile-time errors, but that is rarely a good idea unless you are working with something like COM.

Comment: _"unless you are working with something like COM"_ - which in itself is rarely a super good idea. :D